# Is there a library for indoor mapping for the Kinect 2.0?

Tags: 3d, 2d, kinect, point-cloud-library, slam-algorithm

I am exploring the capabilities that a Kinect has, that can be used in the robotics field.

I am working on a telepresence robot where the Kinect is an important component of the robot. It is in fact the component that is used in order to generate a map of where the robot is located, so that it can navigate smoothly and avoid the obstacles in front of it. 
As I searched on similar projects, I found some applications that are closer, if not the same of what I want to do. The closest application to my research is the folling [project done by MIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY7rScDd5h8)

What I know so far is that the techniques involved in that process are:

- 3D Mapping
- 3D point Cloud
- Simultaneous Localization and Mapping (SLAM)

I currently succeeded in generating a 3D point cloud using the following [tutorial](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~edwardz/tutorials/kinect2/kinect3.html), but did not know what to do next.

I would love to have any information that can be helpful, either a tutorial or a library or something similar. Basically a starting point

Answer (score 1):

Another option to look into is the [Prepose Scripting language](http://www.davevoyles.com/new-prepose-scripting-langauge-kinect-2/), which the Microsoft Research and Kinect teams came out with about 18 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this library is what you are looking for:

http://pointclouds.org/

And I'm actually quite surprised that you haven't found it before as you are using the tag of that precise library on your question.

It has a bunch of tutorials here:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#i-o

Many of those related with the use of Kinect.

And for given you a little more guidance on your personal interest, you should check this implementation of KinFu:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_kinfu_large_scale.php#using-kinfu-large-scale

Hope this is what you were looking for.